# Who to stop spammers attacking mailenable using external domain names?

Tags: spam

We have an issue on our Mailenable with the MTA enabled on MXSCAN software, everything were working fine, but today we have realized that we are only able of sending emails but not receiving.we have checked the logs on MxScan message logs,We have found that a stranger with an external IP and PostOffice (null) and Sender Email ( is not from the local domains ) trying to send to random emails in each millisecond and of course it being blocked , we have Blocked the IP to the Firewall inbound rules as well but still no effect which makes our mail enable so busy.[image: Logs Screen Shot]

Comment: Welcome! You blocked the IP spamming your system at the firewall. What is your question?

Comment: Yes I have blocked it using Firewall, But as you see in the attached photo that it is not taking effect it is still attacking, I have created a new Inbound Rule and added a custom filed in the Scope and blocked the Remote IP and saved the Rule,

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking. If blocking the IP at your perimeter firewall isn't working, then your firewall rule is not properly implemented. Further, the spam messages show in the log as being deleted due to being blacklisted. Again, what is your question?

Comment: yes it is being deleted but it is still making our mailenable server busy which prevents us from receiving any email, what is wrong in the above mentioned steps to block the Ip in firewall